# Microsoft Store Policy - User Generated Content

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have an app that I would like to submit to the Microsoft Store. The app lets users generate content that is stored in a file that can be stored on disk or shared or whatever else you might do with a file. Is that considered "User Generated Content" with respect to the Microsoft Store Policy document? I'm trying to figure out what policies I need to follow. I don't see how I can enforce content policy from within my app if the user generates content and then shares that content with another user of the app (either online or with physical media or whatever). Also, what if I provide access to a website (either one that I own or someone else's) inside the app that has content people can download and view with the app? Does it then fall under "User Generated Content" policy? Any insights would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I have an app that I would like to submit to the Microsoft Store. The
> app lets users generate content that is stored in a file that can be
> stored on disk or shared or whatever else you might do with a file. Is
> that considered "User Generated Content" with respect to the Microsoft
> Store Policy document?

Your app allows user-generated content that can be shared with other users, which does involve "[User-generated content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/publish/store-policies#1112-user-generated-content)" in the Microsoft Store policy.

> I'm trying to figure out what policies I need to follow. I don't see
> how I can enforce content policy from within my app if the user
> generates content and then shares that content with another user of
> the app (either online or with physical media or whatever).

The Microsoft Store [Content Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/publish/store-policies#content-policies) defines what types of content are allowed and what is prohibited. This includes aspects such as the legality, safety, and appropriateness of the content.

> Also, what if I provide access to a website (either one that I own or
> someone else's) inside the app that has content people can download
> and view with the app? Does it then fall under "User Generated
> Content" policy?

These websites in your app fall under **Content Policies**, you need to ensure that this content also complies with Microsoft Store Content Policies.

If you own these sites, you are responsible for ensuring that their content is legal, safe, and does not violate our policies.
If these sites are owned by someone else, you need to ensure that your application does not direct users to illegal, harmful or inappropriate content

Comment: ... Okay, I'm a little confused about how I adhere to the requirements for User Generated Content given the nature of my application. Suppose someone uses the app to create a file with objectionable content. Then the user shares that file with someone either online or with physical media. The person they share it with then opens the file with my app. The same scenario could take place with a simple text editor app. How can I prevent objectionable content from being opened in the app if I am not the one hosting the file?

Comment: It is recommended that your acceptable use policy be clearly defined in your terms of service and community guidelines, and you reserve the right to remove or block access to any content that violates these guidelines. You can implement content filtering algorithms that scan file contents for objectionable content. Or work with a third-party service that specializes in content moderation.

Comment: @user1094779 Have you checked my reply? Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Does it help? Not really :-) ... I would love to be in the Windows Store but scanning user created files for objectionable content is a big burden. The users of the app will have the option to include video, images and text. Any one of which could portray objectionable content. I find it hard to believe that applications in the store all adhere to that requirement. I don't want to argue the policy with you though. I believe what you are saying to me about the policy. Thanks.